# How can I filter tortoisehg (Mercurial) to not show branches containing part of a string?

Tags: regex, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

Our Mercurial/HG repo has a fair amount of wip feature branches, and I would like to be able to create a cleaner view and filter out any branches containing part of a string.

I know I can specify which branches to show, but I would rather like to be able to set a search string that is excluded, since all of those branches include something like **feature_xx**

Something a long the lines of: `not branch_contains("feature")`, possibly using regex? Hiding them from the history/hierarchy view individually would also be an ok solution.

How do I do this in TortoiseHG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface**

You have to understand: Mercurial per se and TortoiseHG are *slightly different* products with own interfaces (CLI vs GUI) and toolsets due to nature

**Face**

If you want only hide some subtrees from main window of Workbench (top-right area), you can activate Filter Toolbar (`View` - `Filter Toolbar` or `Ctrl+S`)

[image: Empty Filter Toolbar]

and apply (previously tested in pure CLI or write and debug in-place) revset ([hg help revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#revsets)) to hide unwanted branches (namely `branch(string or set)` revset and operator `not x`)

Note 1: Entered revset here doesn't restore filtering after restart of THG in new session automatically, you have to do it by hand

Note 2: All and any used revset doesn't disappear after re-launch of THG, but stored in history of toolbar (until manually removed) and can be easy restored later

For your use-case "all branches, not having `feature_` in branch-name" I got in the revset with (simplest) regexp something like

```
! branch('re:(?i)feature_')
```

- `!` (not) to *exclude* from view selected revisions
- `re:` for using regexp for matching all branches with common pattern in naming
- `(?i)` to perform a case-insensitive match on a case-sensitive predicate (match "feature_", "FEATURE_", "Feature_" or even "FeAtUrE_")

PS: just a sample. During testing, with such filter

[image: Excluding release branches]

in repo with branch-list

```
hg branches
1.0.x                       2193:20739d2244a1
default                     2190:efadd9becb86
0.10.x                      2118:4a18ab4b2fed (inactive)
```

I removed from view not only existing release-branches 0.10.x + 1.0.x, but also all future releases, which will follow the same pattern of naming (trailing "0.x")